# How to append data to a PDF document using PDFKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am attempting to append data to an exisiting PDF document using PDFKit with the following code.

```
        PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData: pdfData];

        for (PDFPage *page in document) {
            [pdfDocument insertPage: page atIndex: pdfDocument.pageCount];
        }
```

However, I get the warning:

```
Collection expression type 'PDFDocument *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'
```

So I assume fast enumeration wont work. I also tried enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: but that throws an error. Is there another/better way to do this? The only other alternative I can think of is to do a for loop using document.pageCount and extract the page at that index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does the job. Let me know if there is a better way.

```
        PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:pdfData];

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < document.pageCount; i++) {
            PDFPage *page = [document pageAtIndex: i];

            [document insertPage:page 
                         atIndex:document.pageCount];
        }
```